# Runtime error creating intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to create a test app for a library I am creating.  When my library is called, it creates an intent and starts an activity.

```
intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), video_on_load.class);
myLib.this.startActivity(intent);
```

My program it seems my program is crashing on creating the new Intent.  I tried to why this would happen, and I saw that in my app I have to had the activity to the AndroidManafest, so I added the following line to my manifest:

```
activity android:name="com.example.myLib.video_on_load"></activity>
```

However my app is still crashing with the message "Unfortunately, TestApp has stopped."  I am unsure how to continue.  I am fairly new to android programming, so it may be something simple I missed.  Let me know if you need any other information that would be useful in debugging this problem.

My video_on_load class is as follows:

```
public class video_on_load extends Activity {
    private RelativeLayout layout;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;    

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video_on_load);

        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.video_onLoad_layout);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.video_onLoad_progress);
    }
```

Edit:

Relevent LogCat:

```
  12-28 17:53:23.824: E/AndroidRuntime(25042): java.lang.NullPointerException
  12-28 17:53:23.824: E/AndroidRuntime(25042):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:135)
  12-28 17:53:23.824: E/AndroidRuntime(25042):  at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
  12-28 17:53:23.824: E/AndroidRuntime(25042):  at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3491)
```

video_on_load.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/video_onLoad_layout" >

<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/video_onLoad_progress"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerInParent="true"
             style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you

Comment: What does the Almighty Logcat tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), video_on_load.class);
myLib.this.startActivity(intent);
```

into:

```
intent = new Intent(this, video_on_load.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

As long as you are putting this code somewhere in an Activity, you should be good to go. Note, a An application is has a context, and Application has Activities, and Activities also have a Context. Try reading some documentation on Activities and Context's to get a better understanding.

Your error message shows that something is null in your call, and that it is related to getApplicationContext(). Good luck

Comment: I will read up on everything as soon as I can.  I made this change, and got another exception.  I updated the original post with the new exception.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't following naming conventions so things may be confusing. Your layout is "R.layout.video_on_load" and your nested relative layout is "R.layout.video_onLoad_layout". Is that id actually declared in the XML layout file for "R.layout.video_on_load", that or the progress bar may not exist in your which would cause your Null Pointer Error when you call findViewById(id). Can we see the XML file for your layout?

Correct the resource IDs that you're assigning to variables.

Comment: Sorry about that, coming from C++, not used to all the Java naming conventions.  Updated original post with xml file

Comment: Where are you calling the intent to start your Activity?

Comment: My intent is starting in my library.